# How come these programs are allowed to pass a non-const variable and I can't?

Tags: c++, portaudio

I've been trying to write a program in C++ with portaudio, trying to make a simple audio application, something that can record and play audio just to learn. So I have a class, and in the class, I initialize a variable `PaStreamParameters inputParameters`. Alright so later in the code, I open the stream to record like any other program with `Pa_OpenStream`,

```
err = Pa_OpenStream(
        &stream,
        &inputParameters,
        NULL,
        sampleRate,
        framesPerBuffer,
        paNoFlag,
        recordCallback,
        data);
```

And I get an error that I'm doing an invalid conversion from `int (*)(const void*, const void*, long unsigned int, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo*, PaStreamCallbackFlags, void*)` to an `int (*)(const void*, void*, long unsigned int, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo*, PaStreamCallbackFlags, void*)`; note the second parameter, converting from a `const void*` to a `void*`. And it makes sense as I am, in fact passing a non const variable, and `Pa_OpenStream` was written to have a const input. It is even here in the documentation: http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#a443ad16338191af364e3be988014cbbe. So what's the problem? I've seen in multiple places, `Pa_OpenStream` being passed a non-const parameters. The recording example code, http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record_8c_source.html, initializes `PaStreamParameters  inputParameters, outputParameters;`, mutates them, and passes it to `Pa_OpenStream` just like I did. The Ardour source code, in `libs/backends/portaudio/portaudio_io.cc`, the `open_callback_stream` function initializes two `PaStreamParameters` variables, neither being const, and passes them to `Pa_OpenStream` (in a modified way, checking if it should pass NULL instead).

How do these code work and mine don't? None of them pass const input and output parameters to `Pa_OpenStream` and they work. How do they not get an invalid conversion from `const void*` to `void*`?

audour source code for reference: https://github.com/Ardour/ardour/blob/master/libs/backends/portaudio/portaudio_io.cc

Comment: so the error is in the callback function? should I edit my post to include the code for the callback? I didn't expect that to be the issue

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment, but yes please - or at least the function declaration.  But you probably have enough information now to solve the problem anyway.

Comment: (For context, since I deleted my original comment): the signature of function `recordCallback` looks to be the culprit.

Comment: You can pass a non-const variable to a const-parameter, just not the other way around.

Comment: @JMRC in this case what you pass is irrelevant.  It's the declaration of the function that's different, and for a pointer to a function the types of the parameters must match exactly.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I know, that's why I didn't submit it as an answer. But this question is framed as if he thought this parameter was the problem which it isn't. Just wanted to point that out and explain why.

Comment: @JMRC but I thought your statement added to the confusion.  In the case of function pointer signatures it doesn't matter which is const and which isn't, you could reverse them with the same result.  They just plain don't match.

Comment: The full error message should point to a character in the line where the error occurs. Based on earlier comments, I'm guessing it points to the `r` in the line `recordCallback,` rather than the `&` in the line `&inputParameters,`? That is the kind of detail that is important for debugging. While you are not (necessarily) expected to spot the significance of such details, you are expected to include them in your question. **Copying** the text of the error message is so much more valuable than your *interpretation* of the error message. Also, try adding declarations/definitions to get a [mre].

Comment: (Before I read the comments, I had spotted the fact that your conversion is of a function taking 6 parameters, but your code showed a function taking 8. Even if Paul Sanders had not spotted the culprit, this would have been enough for me to request additional information in the form of the exact error message and types of the arguments and parameters to `Pa_OpenStream`. That's with "arguments" meaning the values you supply, and "parameters" meaning the values expected by the function.)

Comment: @JaMiT The error didn't point to either, it pointed to the last parenthesis of the last line, the `)` in `data);`, which doesn't really help which is why I didn't include it

Comment: @chamington More accurate than *"which doesn't really help"* would be that it doesn't really help **you**. However, if you knew all the details that are relevant, you wouldn't be asking the question, now would you?

Answer (score 3):

C++ has no problem converting a non-const pointer to a const pointer, the two are perfectly compatible and it will do the conversion automatically.  But that's not what the compiler is complaining about here.

It's complaining about the pointer to the callback function, `recordCallback`.  The parameter types declared for a function are part of the type of that function, and they must match exactly or the types are different.

Comment: ohhh huh, thank you, that makes sense, I'll make sure the parameters for recordCallback are what they supposed to be, thank you very much